# how to fix the strange outcome of a if-else statement with new DateTime()

Tags: php

I'm using an 'if-else' statement to change the class of a div-element, but i get the result from the else-clause in state of the result from the if-clause.

I'm using PHP 5.6.
When i debug this statement i get these values for the variables:

```
- $row['gepland'] < new DateTime()  : true  
- new dateTime()    (DateTime)  : 2019-01-23 11:05:51.000000
- $row['gepland']   (string)        : 2019-03-11 00:00:00   
- new DateTime($row['gepland']) < new DateTime():   false
- $class_gepland (string)           : bg-warning p-3
```

First, when I use a string-variable `$row['gepland']` it returns `true`, so I changed this value in a DateTime-object `new DateTime($row['gepland'])`.
Now, the result of the statement returns, as expected, `false`.
so far so good, but the variable `$class_gepland` still is `'bg-warning p-3'`, as shown in the last line of the debug-results.

```
if (new DateTime($row['gepland']) < new DateTime()){
        $class_gepland = 'bg-warning p-3';
    }
else{
        $class_gepland = 'bg-success p-3';
    }
```

So, although the statement returns false, `$class_gepland` is `'bg-warning p-3'` and not `'bg-success p-3'` as I expected.

Comment: As per your debug, `$class_gepland (string): bg-warning p-3` - so how do you verify that its not?

Comment: When i debug the variable, its value is 'bg-warning p-3' and the div element has the wrong color.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://3v4l.org/l0Ep8 - so there's something else that we can't see from the information you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a hard time reproducing this. As the geplan value is larger (it's in the future), the result of the comparison is false, and (correctly) bg-success p-3.

```
$row['gepland'] = "2019-03-11 00:00:00";
$class_gepland = false;

if (new DateTime($row['gepland']) < new DateTime()){
    $class_gepland = 'bg-warning p-3';
}
else {
    $class_gepland = 'bg-success p-3';
}

var_dump($class_gepland);
```

Output:

```
string(14) "bg-success p-3"
```

https://3v4l.org/IE425

Comment: So, that's what I expected to, but in an strange way, i got the wrong value. What can be the difference?

Comment: Do a var_dump of the $row['gepland'] value before the comparison. Make sure it's a string variable. Finally, and this is a bit of a long shot, find out what time your server/PHP is set to. Maybe it's set way into the future.

Comment: $row['gepland'] is a string variable, I checked before. Maybe the server is a bit messed up cause of the snowfall, you never know :) I'll restart the server, maybe this has a good outcome.

Comment: When all else fails, blame mother nature.